# Find decision rule using Rao-Blackwell

Tags: statistics, bayesian, decision-problems

Suppose that an observation $x \in (-1,1)$  comes from a sample model with a parameter $\theta$, with density function:

$$
f(x\mid\theta) = \begin{cases}
 \theta\ if -1 < x < 0\\
      1 - \theta\ if\ 0 \leqslant x < 1
\end{cases}\
$$

a) Consider the decision rule $δ_0(x) = (1 − x)/2$. Find the frequentist risk
$R(θ; δ_0)$ associated with this decision rule.

I got $\theta^3 -\theta^2 +0.5/6$

b) Suppose that the prior distribution for $\theta$ is uniform over the interval $(0,1)$.
Find a Bayes estimator associated with this prior distribution, under the quadratic loss function $L(\theta , d) = (\theta - d)^2$.

c) Using the Rao-Blackwell Theorem, find a decision rule that
dominates $δ_0$ and verify explicitly that this new rule dominates $δ_0$.

I have no idea how to deal with question c). For part b), I'm wondering if this Bayes estimator is $E(\theta\mid x) = (2\theta - 1)^2 +1 $

Please let me know your thoughts. Thank you!

Comment: show your work for b; what did you  get for the posterior density>

Comment: For b, I got $f(θ∣x)=2θ$ if $−1<x<0$ and $2(1−θ)$ if $0⩽x<1$

Comment: and for c) I was trying to factorize $f(x\mid\theta)$ using the indicator function but couldn't get anything so far..